# Output to find the third largest number does not come as expected

Tags: java, arrays

> Given an array of integers, find out the third largest value in the array.

**MyApproach**

## Sample Input #1

remove({1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,0,0,2})

Sample Output #1

{1,2,3,4,5,1,2,2}

## Sample Input #2

remove({0,0,1,2})

Sample Output #2

{1,2}

## Sample Input #3

remove({0,0,0,0})

Sample Output #3

{}

**MyApproach**

@Edit

To find maximum number I sorted the array and returned the maximum number.

Below is my code.

Thank you everyone for your support.

Below is my code:

```
public int thirdLargest(int[] arr)
{
 for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
   int temp=0;
   int large=0;
   int index=0;

       large=arr[i];
       for(int j=i;j<arr.length;j++)
       {
           if(arr[j]>=large)
           {
               large=arr[j];
               index=j;
            }
        }
       temp=arr[i];
       arr[i]=arr[index];
       arr[index]=temp;
 }
 return arr[2];
}
```

Comment: @JFPicard Actual output and expected output which I mentioned at the last.

Comment: Wouldn't the "third largest value" of your 3 examples be `3`, `0`, and `null`?

Comment: @Andreas No,I don't think.

Comment: With this list `1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,0,0,2`, the largest (max) value is `5`, second largest is '4', and *third* largest is `3`. How are you interpreting it differently?

Comment: As far as I can see @Andreas and your code are both correct.  What is wrong are your expectations.

Comment: @Jasonarora You never answered my question. How are you interpreting "third largest value" differently from what I said? The only alternate I can think of is that with `1,2,3,4,4`, `4` is largest, `4` is 2nd largest, and `3` is 3rd largest. If that is your interpretation, please say so in question. --- Also, the question is confusing, since your code and my answer both return a single value, but Sample Output #1, #2, and #3 all show the output being a list. Which is it? Value or list? Please clarify question.

Comment: In your given array 1,2,3,4,4, 4.4 is first largest.I removed that element.Then 4th  is second largest element.I removed that element and last 4 will be the third largest.This is how I interpret and wrote the code.

Comment: @Andreas But now I have changed my approach.I sorted the elements and returned ar[2].which is producing correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static int thirdLargest(int[] array) {
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int thirdLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int number : array) {

        if (largest < number) {
            thirdLargest = secondLargest;
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = number;
        } else if (secondLargest < number) {
            thirdLargest = secondLargest;
            secondLargest = number;
        } else if (thirdLargest < number) {
            thirdLargest = number;
        }
    }

    return thirdLargest;
}
```

Tested with '{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}' input and -1 is returned.

Now after adjusting your code:

```
public static int thirdLargest(int[] arr) {

    int max1 = findMax(arr);
    int p[] = remove(arr, max1);
    int max2 = findMax(p);
    int q[] = remove(p, max2);
    int max3 = findMax(q);
    return max3;
}

static int findMax(int[] arr) {
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= max) {
            max = arr[i];

        }
    }
    return max;
}

static int[] remove(int[] arr, int max) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == max) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    int p[] = new int[arr.length - 1];
    for (int m = 0, n = 0; m < arr.length; m++) {

        if (index != m) {
            p[n] = arr[m];
            n++;
        }
    }
    return p;

}
```

Reason: `remove` method should remove only one ocurrence of max value.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't remove data from the array you are given. You are asking to output the 3rd largest value, therefore you should only output and not modify the array in the input at all. This array could need to be used later on, and it may be assumed that since you are only finding the third largest, the input array would remain the same.

I would do this by keeping an array of 3 integers. The integers correspond to the largest 3 numbers, `arr[0]` is the largest, `arr[1]` is the second largest, and `arr[2]` is the third largest. Then, loop through each of the numbers in the input, and if it is larger than any of the 3 numbers, push the other 2 numbers down a position, and insert the new number.

```
public static int find3rdLargest(int [] arr){
    int [] largest3Numbers = {Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MIN_VALUE,Integer.MIN_VALUE}; // Initialize array with minimum int values possible, since we are finding largest
    for(int i : arr){ // Loop over each item in input
        if(i > largest3Numbers[0]){ // if its the largest number
            largest3Numbers[2] = largest3Numbers[1]; // set 2nd largest to 3rd
            largest3Numbers[1] = largest3Numbers[0]; // set largest to 2nd
            largest3Numbers[0] = i; // set new largest
        }else if (i > largest3Numbers[1]){ // if it is the second largest number
            largest3Numbers[2] = largest3Numbers[1]; // set 2nd largest to 3rd
            largest3Numbers[1] = i; // set new 2nd largest
        }else if (i > largest3Numbers[2]){ // if it is the 3rd largest
            largest3Numbers[2] = i; // set it to 3rd largest
        }
    }
    return largest3Numbers[2]; // return 3rd largest
}
```

I tested this function by running:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int[] shouldOutput4 = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
    int[] shouldOutput0 = { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    System.out.println("Should output 4: " + find3rdLargest(shouldOutput4));
    System.out.println("Should output 0: " + find3rdLargest(shouldOutput0));

}
```

Which gave me the output:

```
Should output 4: 4
Should output 0: 0
```

Comment: Technically, the second example has no 3rd largest number, so result should be `null` or `Optional.empty()` (Java 8).

Comment: @Andreas Sir  Can you check what is wrong in my code?